# HLSL correct pixel position in deferred shading

Tags: directx, hlsl, directx-11

In OpenGL, I am using the following in my pixel shaders to get the correct pixel position, which is used to sample diffuse, normal, position gbuffer textures:

```
ivec2 texcoord = ivec2(textureSize(unifDiffuseTexture) * (gl_FragCoord.xy / UnifAmbientPass.mScreenSize));
```

So far, this is what I do in HLSL:

```
float2 texcoord = input.mPosition.xy / gScreenSize;
```

Most notably, in GLSL I am using `textureSize()` to get accurate pixel position. I am wondering, is there a HLSL equivalent to `textureSize()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HLSL, you have [`GetDimensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

But it may be costlier than reading it from a constant buffer, even if it looks easier to use at first to do quick tests.

Also, you have alternative, using `SV_Position` and [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509694%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), just use the `xy` as an `uint2`, you remove the need of an user interpolator carrying a texture coordinate to index the screen.

Here the full documentation of a [`TextureObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509700%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)